# How do we calculate the radius of convergence of a Taylor series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

On *Maclaurin series* we can compute the radius of convergence of a power series $S$, on an open disk $B(z_{0},R)$, provided that the function which is represented by $S$, is analytic on the disk of convergence.

To compute this $R$ we calculate the minimum distance between the point of expanxion $z_0$ and the nearest singularity $z_s$ of the function, such that $|z_0-z_s|<R$, since our point of expansion is $z_0=0$, $R$ becomes some value greater, but not equal to, the module of $|z_s|$.

Can we apply the same method when calculating the radius of convergence of a *Taylor series*?  Which point of expansion is some $z_0 \not =0$.

Do we have to take special considerations?

Very Thankful.

Comment: Yes. What works for Maclaurin works, mutatis mutandis, for Taylor.

Comment: This amounts to a simple translation of coordinates.  So, yes.

Comment: Indeed, this theorem (and most theorems in complex analysis about power series) are usually proved for Taylor series. I'm surprised that you found a source that did it just for Maclaurin series instead.